# Stop users from breaking the code by entering incorrect input

Tags: python

How you would stop a user from breaking the code by entering an incorrect function? For example:

```
category = raw_input("Please choose the number of the category you which to play with!")

if category == 1:
    print "Thankyou for choosing",category,".The game will commence shortly!"

if category == 2:
    print "Thankyou for choosing",category,".The game will commence shortly!"

if category == 3:
    print "Thankyou for choosing",category,".The game will commence shortly!"

else:
    print "Incorrect input choose again!"
```

This works but when I put a correct input in the code it still comes up with 'Incorrect input choose again!' How would I go about to solve this?

Comment: `category = int(raw_input("Please choose the number of the category you which to play with!"))` should do the trick.

Comment: Your current problem is you are comparing a `str` (which is the return type of `raw_input`) to an `int`. But in general, see the duplicate to handle robustly accepting user input for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string, and you compare it to an `int`. That is why you are always getting to the `else` clause of your `if` statements. You should cast to `int` like so before comparing:

```
category = int(raw_input("Please choose the number of the category you which to play with!"))
```